# SQL Server Agent fails to start in Failover cluter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering, sql-server-agent

The SQL server agent in a cluster (as a cluster resource) fails to start. I'm looking for error logs to give me a clue, but so far, all it says is: "failed to start". What could be the possible issues? Where can I see a more detailed error log?

Update: I've checked the sql server logs, the cluster event logs and the windows event logs.

Comment: Can you specify what logs you have checked so far?

Comment: Does it always fail to start, or does it eventually start?

Comment: Also, does the Agent fail to start on both (all) nodes in the cluster, or only one certain ones? Has the SQL Agent ever started successfully in this clustered instance?

Answer (score 4):

There are logs in a few places. For the Agent logs please see the screenshot:

[image: Agent Logs]

In Object Explorer expand SQL Server Agent \ Error Logs.

Comment: Not seeing the screenshot, uploaded twice. Hmmm.